# Оцените защитные качества капчи

Tags: captcha, php

Учусь писать капчу на сайте, готовыми решениями пользоваться не хочется, хочется научиться самому. Думаю, вы меня понимаете. Нашел урок по созданию капчи. Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли эту капчу использовать на серьёзных проектах? То есть защитит ли она от спама?

Урок по этой ссылке:

[Creating a PHP Captcha](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/creating-a-php-captcha)

Answer (score 2):

Смотря что подразумевать под спам-ом. Если использование роботами формы защищенной данной капчей - то не сильно на нее надейтесь. От роботов лучше защищаться дополнительными полями скрытыми от пользователей через CSS

Comment: Можете подксказать, как это сделать?

Comment: Например:

  <style>
      input.email { display: none }
  </style>
  <form ...>
      <input class="email" name="email" value="" />
      ...
  </form>

И соответственно если приходит запрос с заполненным email - это спам.

Comment: то есть робот все поля всегда заполняет, да?

Comment: в 99% случаев, особенно если это `email`, `url` и т.п.

Comment: Тогда это будет надежно, да?

Comment: Из личного опыта - достаточно надежно, правда до тех пор пока не напишут специализированный робот заточенный под вашу форму, но тогда капчу придется делать более интелектуальной

Comment: Спасибо, друг!

Answer (score 0):

Капча - это тупиковый подход. Нужно что-то новое! :)

ЗЫ: по теме, капча элементарная, ломается без каких бы то не было проблем стандартными средствами :)

Comment: Поясните дилетанту. Ломается подменой в SESSION MD5 в соответствии с Input ?

Если так, то можно-ли сломать если MD5 класть в локальный файл (или базу), а в SESSION класть имя этого файла ?

Comment: нет, я имел ввиду что распознается текст ботом изображенный на капче

Comment: А каким спосабами ещё можно взломать капчу? Я только про ботов-распознавателей знал, но ведь  трудные капчи, например как у яндекса не распознаешь.

Comment: >> но ведь трудные капчи, например как у яндекса не распознаешь.

Это миф :)

Answer (score 0):

Каптча отлично защищает лишь в том случае, когда о ней никто не знает, как только она выходит в массы и начинает пользоваться популярностью - под нее пишут ботов.

Более-менее (имхо) работающий метод - это уникальный вопрос-ответ, все остальное лажа.